# Highcharts pie charts showing 2 percent symbols

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

I have some pie charts on my page showing percentages. For my series data I am just passing in pairs of strings and integers, like `['GroupA', 10], ['GroupB', 70]`. It correctly splits up the sections mathematically, but for some reason it's adding 2 percent symbols instead of just 1.

[image: pie chart showing 2 percent symbols]

Actual result: "GroupA%: 12.5%"

Expected result: "GroupA: 12.5%"

I was looking in the Highcharts documentation for a way to configure this in the options but didn't find anything. It seems like this should not be the default behavior but it is. How can I set it to just display one percent (%) symbol at the end?

Comment: Can you add your configurations in your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After revisiting my code I found I had an HTML tag in my options that was causing the 2 % symbols to show up. It was taken from some sample code I found online.

```
options = {
            plotOptions: {
                pie: { allowPointSelect: true, cursor: 'pointer', dataLabels: { enabled: true, format: '<b>{point.name}%</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %' } }
            },
        };
```

I'm just showing the relevant code here. My format was like this:

```
format: '<b>{point.name}%</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
```

I had to change it to this:

```
format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f}%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided your configurations, the issue maybe due to custom configurations happening.

The expected result Highcharts configurations can be found below.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },

    plotOptions: {
    
   
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled:true,
                distance: '30%',
                 formatter: function() {
            console.log(this.point.name);
                return (this.point.name +" "+ this.point.y+"%");
          }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            ['GroupA', 10], ['GroupB', 70],
            
        ]
    }]
});
```

The working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pratyushhg/jawugvL6/4/) can be found here.